# How to get to my localhost directory with the command line

Tags: sass, command-prompt

Am styling my website using SASS but now that I restarted the machine I can't access the directory where I have my stylesheet.

Since am using xampp. All files are saved in the local host folder. This is the result when I try to search:

[image]

I did this: 
cd\
C:\xampp\htdocs\

How can I access my htdocs folder?

Answer (score 1):

With `cd\` goes to the root directory but then you have to write `cd` and the relative path: `cd xampp\htdocs\`. Otherwise if you write `cd C:\xampp\htdocs\` doesn't matter in what directory you are, goes to `C:\xampp\htdocs\` directly.